# Submit button redirect to url with parameter in box

Tags: php, html

I want to make a text box that you have to enter string (max 10 characters) with submit button that the action will redirect you to specific url with this entered string.
for example: String entered (Angel) redirect url: ([www.example.com/info/Angel](http://www.example.com/info/Angel)).

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need some JavaScript. What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)